# Adding a "count" when pasting

Tags: excel-2013

Sorry not sure how to be specific so here is an example:

In a column I have

MyChar1
MyChar2
MyChar3

I have to enter this until I reach MyChar500. Is there a way I can do this with format painter or something similar?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the three cells.

Find the fill handle. It is the little square at the lower right corner of the selection. Click and drag it down to row 500.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I just found that as well ;-)